# SlidingPaneLayout with a MapFragment in right pane. Map is not showing when left pane is on screen (on small screens)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps-v2, slidingmenu, mapfragment

I have a SlidingPaneLayout with a ListView in the left  pane and a MapFragment in the right pane.

Her is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_pane"
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

The problem is when the SlidingPaneLayout is showed on a small screen (smaller then 200dp + 300dp in my case). Then the map cant be seen until the right pane is fully on screen. I want the map to be visible even when the left pane is on screen(visible to the right of the ListView).

Not like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5kUE.png). I want the right pane to show the map.

Is it possible, and how?

Comment: What do you mean "visible to the left of the ListView"?  You have `android:layout_gravity="left"` in your `ListView`.

Comment: Sorry, meant right of the ListView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074872/android-slidingpanelayout-main-view-is-hidden/17075245#17075245

Comment: @sogasg How did you manage to intercept onItemClickListener on the listView?. cause, my xml looks just like yours but My list can not get the focus and it's not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_pane"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

From what I can tell, `android:layout_gravity="left"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` are both unnecessary.  Everything else should be fine.  I'm not sure what you're expecting.  I have a feeling that the reason that the map can't be seen is a product of the map itself.  Try replacing it with something else.  It should show up just fine.

Sample reference: [Exploring SlidingPaneLayout](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/2765-exploring-slidingpanelayout/), [How to use the SlidingPaneLayout](http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/how-to-use-the-slidingpanelayout/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Yes, with other views its showing fine. Its just the map that disappear when the left pane is on screen (for smaller screens). Btw.: I can even see that the map buttons for zoom is not disappearing as I swipe the map, but at once a swipe begins the map disappear. 

The android:layout_weight="1" is used to make the map span the whole screen when the screen is wider then 300dp.